# Get data according _id

Tags: mongodb

I try to query MongoDB inside nodejs to get data for _id x I use

```
async function getTestData(id){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, keepAlive: 1 }, function(err, client) {
            const dbo = client.db("test");
            var query = { _id: id };
            dbo
                .collection("smscripts")
                .find(query)
                .project({ 'data' : 1})
                .toArray(function(err, items) {
                    err
                        ? reject(err)
                        : resolve(items);

                });

        });

    });
}
```

Query is

```
{ _id: '5dada7dfdca94dbaf65d9547' }
```

But I always get back an empty array. Anybody can help me out why the array is always empty? By the way, err is null. The id definitely exists.

Comment: You probably want `{ _id: ObjectId('5dada7dfdca94dbaf65d9547' ) }`.

Answer (score 1):

in mongo db **_id**  are prefix with  **ObjectId**

so you need value first try this

```
id = ObjectId("507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e")
```

and then compare it to ID.

hope it helps

Comment: Finally I missed the var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

Comment: Yes this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

- First You need to import..

  **`import { ObjectId } from "bson"`**
- Then in Your code " *var query = { _id: id };* " replace it with this..

  **`var query = { '_id' : ObjectId(id) }`**
- Then, in your code you are using .toArray() method. this would takes more time to 
  convert result to array. so you need to use  `await` keyword before moving on.
- Using Async-Await pattern this is very simple ..

  ```
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, keepAlive: 1 })
          .catch(err => { console.log(err); });

  if (!client) return;
  ```

  try {

  ```
      const dbo = client.db('test');

      let collection = dbo.collection('smscripts');

      let query = { '_id' : ObjectId(id) };
      let projection =  { 'data' : 1 }  ; 

      let cursor = await collection.find(query, projection).toArray();

      console.log(cursor);
      return cursor; 

  } catch (err) {

      console.log(err);
  } finally {

      client.close();
  }
  ```
- hope this works for you.